# converted local language using google input tool not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, django

I am using the following js code to convert local language from English in a django app. It is working locally, but on aws, display is not working, what i can see is only symbols of question mark.

```
    // Load the Google Transliteration API

  google.load("elements", "1", {
        packages: "transliteration"
      });

  function onLoad() {
    var options = {
      sourceLanguage: 'en',
      destinationLanguage: ['ml'],
      shortcutKey: 'ctrl+m',
      transliterationEnabled: true
    };
    // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
    // options.

    var control =  new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);
    // Enable transliteration in the textfields with the given ids.    
   var ids = [ "lang", "langu", "language" ];
    control.makeTransliteratable(ids);

    // Show the transliteration control which can be used to toggle between
    // English and Hindi and also choose other destination language.
    // control.showControl('translControl');

  }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
```

The error on console is

```
A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, https://www.google.com/uds/?file=elements&v=1&packages=transliteration, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more details.
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read the link in your error message?
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104

It seems pretty clear what the error is stating: you are trying to include a script from another domain which could affect your performance and get blocked by some slow browsers/connections.

The code you are including is the following:

https://www.google.com/uds/?file=elements&v=1&packages=transliteration

```
if (window['google'] != undefined && window['google']['loader'] != undefined) {
if (!window['google']['elements']) {
window['google']['elements'] = {};
google.elements.Version = '1.0';
google.elements.JSHash = '7ded0ef8ee68924d96a6f6b19df266a8';
google.elements.LoadArgs = 'file\x3delements\x26v\x3d1\x26packages\x3dtransliteration';
}
google.loader.writeLoadTag("css", google.loader.ServiceBase + "/api/elements/1.0/7ded0ef8ee68924d96a6f6b19df266a8/transliteration.css", false);
google.loader.writeLoadTag("script", google.loader.ServiceBase + "/api/elements/1.0/7ded0ef8ee68924d96a6f6b19df266a8/transliteration.I.js", false);
}
```

I would suggest you to download the `css` and the `script`
 and put it in your asset pipeline.
I would not delegate `google.loader.writeLoadTag` to load it.

**UPDATE**

I am afraid you misunderstood my answer. The code I mentioned above is the content of the script causing the error. I suggested to retrieve the full url for the css and the javascript:

- https://www.google.com/uds/api/elements/1.0/7ded0ef8ee68924d96a6f6b19df266a8/transliteration.css
- https://www.google.com/uds/api/elements/1.0/7ded0ef8ee68924d96a6f6b19df266a8/transliteration.I.js

Now you can choose if you want to refer to those assets using the external link or if you want to download both the `css` and the `js` and add them to your asset pipeline

Comment: I have added the code you mentioned, but no difference, could you show me the link to download the mentioned css and js. This is the project link I am working on http://cjquora-dev3.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/

Comment: I provided it as external line now the console error is Access to Font at 'http://quorabucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff' from origin 'http://cjquora-dev3.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://cjquora-dev3.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @SbijuMon was this answer helpful?